# Laravel 5, orderByRaw using field and column doesn't exists

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have problems with Eloquent/QueryBuilder when I use orderByRaw function I got exception column doesnt exists, but the column is already exists into database.

Here is the exception:

```
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  function field(integer, integer) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The status column into database is integer.
Here is my code:

```
$orderedStatuses = implode(',', [4]);
$users->orderByRaw(\DB::raw("FIELD(status, $orderedStatuses)"));
```

...also, if I use users.status I got the same error.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: `orderByRaw` already expects raw SQL. You don't need to use `DB::raw` inside of it too.

Comment: Additionally, to what fubar wrote, the MySQL [FIELD()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function accepts strings as arguments. You are, apparently, passing integers. The error message says nothing about the non-existant column you mentioned. It's about incorrectly used function.

Answer (score 1):

You mixed both the methods.

```
$users->orderBy(\DB::raw("FIELD(status, $orderedStatuses)"));
```

Or

```
$users->orderByRaw("FIELD(status, $orderedStatuses)");
```

Answer (score 0):

`orderByRaw` expects raw SQL, you have to pass string in the argument of `orderByRaw`.

Example:

```
$users->orderByRaw('field1 ASC, field2 DESC, field3 DESC,...');
```